# Word meaning not to do something for a while to get a different feeling once you do it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What would be a word or short phrase meaning not to do something for a certain period of time in order for it to feel better, or stronger, once you finally do it?

I'm looking for a better way to say this, for example:

> What are the effects of not eating foods of a certain flavors for a few weeks in order to develop a more developed taste for it?

Though this of course makes me think of delayed gratification but I don't think it really applies here.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of "resensitize"?

Comment: _Reculer pour mieux sauter_ used to be common among educated English speakers.

Comment: Could you rewrite the example sentence with a `_____` placeholder where you want the word or phrase to go?

Comment: Abstain; but it lacks the concept of anticipation of pleasure later.

Comment: @Xanne I much rather `abstaining to eat` than `not eating` thank you!

Comment: @k1eran Nope I can't

Comment: @Halhex Why not ?

Comment: Halhex - we don't "abstain to eat"; we **abstain from eating**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

**absence makes the heart grow fonder**  [TDF](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Absence) an idiom

> - A separation causes one to feel even more positive about the absent    person or thing.

As in:

We'll see if absence makes the heart grow fonder after our time apart.

Comment: That's a pretty way to say it, but I don't think it applies to the situation here.

Answer (score 0):

> *Patience is bitter, but its fruit is sweet.*
>             *― Aristotle*

So you could say perhaps:

> *Patience is bitter, but its fruit is sweet* so let's wait until Christmas to have a turkey & ham for dinner!

According to [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/16892-patience-is-bitter-but-its-fruit-is-sweet) the quote is from Aristotle, but I've read [other](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Patience) opinions online.

Comment: Again I don't see this applying to the example, maybe my question isn't worded correctly, I tried to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

`Fast` conveys the notion of not eating foods for a period time.

Comment: Which is not even what the example is about. I would not use `fast` about a specific food.